# file path from NSData

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdata

I have NSData that I'm loading from a filePath. The data is then getting passed around and I need the filePath for where the data came from.

What's the easiest way to do this short of passing the filePath around as an extra parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap both in a container object that represents the file, e.g.

```
@interface File : NSObject

@property (strong) NSData *fileContents;
@property (copy) NSString *filePath;

// perhaps, even a nice constructor to fill these properties
- (id)initWithFilePath:(NSString *)filePath;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

While you should probably create a separate struct or class that contains the data you need, you can also add an association to NSData.

You can even do it as a category on NSData for convenience...  assuming you are using a string... use NSURL if using a URL...  that way, none of your other code needs to change... you can still use your NSData as before, with the newly added property.

NOTE: There are lots of reasons to use or not use categories.  I assume you will make the choice best for your code situation, and defer the wars over good/bad use of categories to others.

Try something like this...

NSData+AssociatedFilePath.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (AssociatedFilePath)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *filePath;
@end
```

NSData+AssociatedFilePath.m

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char kFilePath;

@implementation NSData (AssociatedFilePath)

- (void)setFilePath:(NSString*)filePath
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kFilePath, filePath, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSString*)filePath
{
  return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kFilePath);
}

@end
```

Now, in your code, you can do this...

```
NSData *data = // whatever you do to create the data object..
data.filePath = someFilePath;
```

Whenever you want the file path of a NSData object...

```
NSString *filePath = myNSDataObject.filePath;
```

Since it is a category, you can use this on any NSData object, and if a file path was never set, it will just return nil.

This is a general solution for any time you need to add behavior to an existing class (of course, following appropriate practices for when to best use categories).

Comment: While this is a valid way to do it and a good use of the newish associated object runtime calls, I think you should only do this when you *really* have to, it's not particularly elegant. A simple container class such as that suggested by @joerick is more appropriate here, is a better way of encapsulating a model object and makes for more maintainable code.